# Imagination-based questions

Tags: discussion

Why doesn’t Physics SE accept imagination-based theory, man?

It just makes a person feel so bad when he asked an imagination-based question and it just get closed by higher members (like Qmechanic). Does imagination-based theories cost this site much money?

Comment: What is an "imagination based theory"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All theory started as an imagination and they are not forbidden here.

What is forbidden:

1. Non-mainstream science ([more clearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience)).
2. Unclear questions. It must be clear in the terminology of the today mainstream physics.
3. Content posted as question, while it is not (like simply declaring someone’s own personal theory for open discussion).

I think your posts have fallen into these categories.

If you can formulate your post to avoid these, it will likely be welcomed.

However, you can have an open discussion about it in the site chatroom (*[The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71)*).